# Is there a way to have our own app to upload its crash repot?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Not sure if that is possible. But what happens is, sometimes our app randomly crashes. We don't know what exactly the problem is. Is there a way for us to get the crash report off user's iphone? By code, or by another app?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your great answers. I will try the crash reporter lib first and will see if that work out well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the user who decides from Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage whether to automatically send crash reports or not.

You can also use a third party component to get detailed information about crash events, for example [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I found out this is actually the easiest way to do it. We can have clients get the crash report from there and email it in.

Answer (score 2):

---

You can inject a third party code in your app, which would basically save your crash reports and thereafter you can use them for analysis. The way we do is capture any crash logs and upload them to the app server, which uses the info to display through a user-friendly web Interface (access controlled for admin purposes).

A great open source Crash Reporter library can be found here https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in 3rd party services for crash reporting for iOS it's hard to go past [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com). Very fast crash reporting, simple installation, great response times to queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also mention the [TestFlight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.0/), which is free and easy to use, and allows you to gather crash reports easily from all your testers, and also do remote logging and other stuff. I used it on a location based app I was working on a while ago, and it was very helpful with debugging