# Capturing and sending crash logs to the server

Tags: ios, objective-c

If there is a crash for an application, can I capture the crash logs and send it to a server right after the crash. I guess my question really is if the app crashed can I use the network api to send some data to the server.

Comment: Take a look at PLCrashReporter framework. https://www.plcrashreporter.org/ to get the crashlogs of your application within your application. Then send it to your webserver using Networking API. Why not use HockeyApp or Crittercism for it ?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864075/is-there-a-way-to-have-our-own-app-to-upload-its-crash-repot) and see if it helps you.

Comment: not possible immediately after app crash you can do it on next app launch.

Comment: When the app did crash it is in an unsafe state, you shouldn't not do any that makes it worse. Using networking API can make it worse. Send it on the next startup!

Comment: keeping the open source libraries on side: what exactly are you given do you still have access to objects in memory. Can you have access to those memory objects? The reason I am asking is I am trying to get user state as to what package the user was in?

Comment: No, you don't really (in a safe way) have those and really can't do a lot in that crash state anyway. Here is an introduction from the developer of PLCrashReporter: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of services out there to do this... HockeyApp & TestFlight spring to mind.

Update: HockeyApp has just released a Mac Application 'HockeyCoach' to allow you to view crash reports within a native App, with awesome functionality like viewing the source code referenced in the crash log etc...

I highly reccomend you check it out: http://hockeyapp.net/releases/hockeycoach/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several solutions that provide this functionality. One of them that I'm intimately familiar with (and works very well) is Apigee's Mobile Analytics (http://apigee.com/docs/enterprise/content/analyze_apps).

One of the important points for dealing with crash logs is to save a copy of your .dSYM. This is needed to symbolicate the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Crashlytics. Extremely simple to incorporate into app and is completely free.